# How can I send email Multipart with JavaMail?

Tags: java, wildfly-10

I have a random error with my web app in Struts2 when java code send a mail:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    javax.activation.UnsupportedDataTypeException: no object DCH for MIME type multipart/mixed; 
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1290)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
```

I have deployed file war in WILDFLY 10 (Jdk 1.8) and inside war in folder WEB-INF/lib there are these libraries: 
activation-1.1.jar  and mail-1.4.jar.

Sometimes sending the email works but random I see the error above. 
All emails have no attachments and the code is always the same.

I am going crazy,  I'm doing email test in Test environment and it always works.

I checked folder "modules/system/layers/base/javax/mail/api/main" in Wildfly and founded "javax.mail-1.5.5.jar", in "/modules/system/layers/base/javax/activation/api/main" there is "activation-1.1.1.jar"

Any idea?
thank a lots

Answer (score 1):

I founded solution before send email with this code

```
MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap(); 
mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml"); 
mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain"); 
mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed"); 
mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content- handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add this part of code before sending mail in your code:

```
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader( getClass().getClassLoader() );
```

Comment: I founded solution with code in my post , using MailcapCommandMap . Thank you